# How to apply Normalisation using the MinMaxScaler() to all Columns, but Exclude the Categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, max, min, minmax

I am new to using the `MinMaxScaler`, so please do not bite my head of if this is a very, very simple question. Below, I have the following datatset:

`sample_df.head(2)`

```
ID     S_LENGTH     S_WIDTH     P_LENGTH     P_WIDTH     SPECIES
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      3.5          2.5          5.6         1.7        VIRGINICA
2      4.5          5.6          3.4         8.7         SETOSA
```

Therefore, how to I apply normalisation to this dataset using the following code below to all my columns, excluding the `ID` and `SPECIES` columns?

I basically want to use the `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` to apply normalisation, so that all the features are in a range of 0 and 1.

This is the code I am using...

```
min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(sample_df)
```

...but when I execute it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SETOSA'
```

Any help on how to accomplish what I want to do is much appreciated!

Also, my sincere apologies if this is a really dumb question, **but I am new to this**.

Thank you!

**EDIT (SHOWING ERROR):**

Alternatively, if I do this...

```
min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(sample_df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH']])

sample_df.head(2)
```

...I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this will be very helpful but, you can get the `numeric` columns with:

```
num_df = df[[i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes != 'O']]

num_df
Out[126]: 
   ID  S_LENGTH  S_WIDTH  P_LENGTH  P_WIDTH
0   1       3.5      2.5       5.6      1.7
1   2       4.5      5.6       3.4      8.7
```

and then apply the `MinMaxScaler` on it:

```
min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(num_df)

Out[129]:
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

**EDIT**:
Using your `df`:

```
df
Out[162]: 
   ID  S_LENGTH  S_WIDTH  P_LENGTH  P_WIDTH    SPECIES
0   1       3.5      2.5       5.6      1.7  VIRGINICA
1   2       4.5      5.6       3.4      8.7     SETOSA
```

Use the following code:

```
num_df = min_max.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame((df[[i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes != 'O']])))
num_df.columns = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes != 'O']
cat_df = (df[[i for i in df.columns if df[i].dtypes == 'O']])
res = pd.merge(num_df,cat_df,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

which will give you:

```
print(res)

    ID  S_LENGTH  S_WIDTH  P_LENGTH  P_WIDTH    SPECIES
0  0.0       0.0      0.0       1.0      0.0  VIRGINICA
1  1.0       1.0      1.0       0.0      1.0     SETOSA
```

Try line by line the code and let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. But when I do that, and try and re-sample my data, I get this error: ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample'```

Comment: Can you please show me your code so that I can see where the error comes from?

Comment: I have added the code where the error shows.

Comment: I think this is because ```MinMaxScaler``` returns an array. Try changing your code to this: ```import pandas as pd```,     ```sample_df = pd.DataFrame(min_max.fit_transform(sample_df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH']]))```, ```sample_df.head(2)```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, which prevented the error. But when re-sampling the data, I lose the column names and it only shows them two columns.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. So let me understand what you're looking for. You would like to Normalise the numerical variables in a dataframe but also keep the categorical ones in the same dataframe right? If that, I will update my answer and help you get that. Just confirm please

Comment: Correct. That is exactly what I want to do. Normalise the numerical columns, but retain all the columns in the Normalised dataframe.